# After a freeze, /home on another disk not mounting on startup

Tags: boot, mount, kubuntu, 19.10, fstab

My machine froze, and I had to pull the cable.

As I boot it back up, I'm stuck in the login screen, most likely because all of sudden the `/home` of my user is not mounted on startup.

It seems to be present in `fstab`. Also, whenever I boot the machine, the `Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress...` thing shows. Perhaps it interrupts the mount process?

The disk holding `/home` is a fresh new one, that was working just fine for ~3weeks so far.

How do I mount `/home` automatically?

Comment: Please see if my answer helps you `fsck` both your / and /home partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check your file systems for both / and /home...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem(s)"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number(s) you found earlier

  - fsck both / and /home partitions
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Looks like everything works now, multiple things were fixed according to fsck. I didn't have to boot a Live even, just `CTRL+ALT+F3`in the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

A sudden power interruption can eventually cause big damage. Indeed, the failure to startup in your case may be due to problems with the partition containing your /home folders.

First, you may attempt if checking and repairing the file system solves the issue. For this, work from a live session started from a live DVD or live USB.

If problems persist after checking the file system ,or if the repair fails, you will have no other option than to reinstall. Fundamentally, that is the only certain way to recover from a file system damaging system interruption.

Comment: Since 18.04, you can no longer run `fsck` from Recovery Mode. It has to be done when booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: OK, updated my answer.